# Variable to called stored procedure only works if it comes from input variable

Tags: mysql

I have 2 mysql procedures. One calls the other. I am running them via `phpmyadmin`. If the first procedure specifies an input variable of a type date, and then passes that to the sub procedure(and so I invoke this procedure from `phpmyadmin` and supply a date), everything works fine. However if I try to declare that variable in the first procedure and assign it a value programatically and then pass it, it acts very oddly. I am pretty sure this has to do with variable types and the `@` symbol but I have not yet figured out how to make it work properly.

Procedure 1

```
BEGIN
SET @dayToRun = NULL;
SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL -1 DAY) INTO @dayToRun;
SELECT concat("Running analytics for date:",@dayToRun);
SELECT concat("Running PopulatePreviousDayData@", NOW());
CALL DataAnalysis_PopulatePreviousDayData();
SELECT concat("Running Generate Main Data Set@", NOW());
CALL DataAnalysis_GenerateMainDataSet(@dayToRun);
```

Procedure 2 (Where @p0 is a date input variable)

```
SET @indate = @p0;
SELECT "Starting gmds";
SELECT concat("Input Date:",@indate);
SELECT concat("Input Date:",indate);
SELECT concat('Input Date:',@indate);
```

You can see whats going on by looking at the concats. Only the one without the @ sign is valid, the others don't even print out the first string. However this procedure works with the variable as if it was @, and this works just fine when called using phpmyadmin and supplying a date variable.

```
concat("Input Date:",@indate)
NULL

concat("Input Date:",indate)
Input Date:2016-04-06

concat('Input Date:',@indate)
NULL
```

And whenever that variable is used in a query the procedure breaks.

Answer (score 0):

It appears using the @p0 syntax causes this. If I instead declare a variable and assign it via the name of the parameter itself it works ok.